# Get only the first element of a list of links in a webpage with Python

Tags: python, file, hyperlink, urllib2, html

If i have a web page with a list of links like this:

```
Device  Type    Filename    Size    Date Added
/        /      link1.zip        /          /
/        /      link2.zip        /          /
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

how can i get only the first link and put it into a variable (url) so as to be able to download it with a HTTP request with urllib2?

Comment: Python variables don't begin with `$`.

Comment: @unwind yep, a small oversight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the HTML. Look at [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for a commonly used, robust, HTML parser.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what i wanted. Very helpful.